# Convert shapefile with lists to data frame in R

Tags: shapefile, r, convert, data-frame

I would like to ask some help for converting a shapefile to data frame. I downloaded data related to roads from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/roads/). I imported the shapefile using `shapefiles` package like the following.

```
foo <- read.shp("ne_10m_roads_north_america.shp")
```

Then,I checked str(foo) and saw the following. This is just the beginning part.

```
> str(foo)
List of 2
 $ shp   :List of 49183
  ..$ :List of 8
  .. ..$ record        : int 1
  .. ..$ content.length: int 656
  .. ..$ shape.type    : int 3
  .. ..$ box           : Named num [1:4] -119.6 37.8 -119.6 37.9
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "xmin" "ymin" "xmax" "ymax"
  .. ..$ num.parts     : int 1
  .. ..$ num.points    : int 79
  .. ..$ parts         : int 0
  .. ..$ points        :'data.frame':   79 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ X: num [1:79] -120 -120 -120 -120 -120 ...
  .. .. ..$ Y: num [1:79] 37.9 37.9 37.9 37.9 37.9 ...
  ..$ :List of 8
  .. ..$ record        : int 2
  .. ..$ content.length: int 40
  .. ..$ shape.type    : int 3
  .. ..$ box           : Named num [1:4] -119.8 39.1 -119.7 39.1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "xmin" "ymin" "xmax" "ymax"
  .. ..$ num.parts     : int 1
  .. ..$ num.points    : int 2
  .. ..$ parts         : int 0
  .. ..$ points        :'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ X: num [1:2] -120 -120
  .. .. ..$ Y: num [1:2] 39.1 39.1
```

I usually do something like this.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(foo), nrow=100, byrow=T))
```

But, it seems that each list had different numbers of rows. So I am not sure if this approach is right. I have also tried the following. `do.call(rbind)` will be probably slow even if it works. `rbindlist()` indicates the numbers of columns different among items. `tidyr` got a nice new function called `unnest()` which would work, but R crashed.

```
> test<- do.call(rbind.data.frame, foo)

Error in data.frame(record = 1L, content.length = 656L, shape.type = 3L,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 4, 79

> test <- rbindlist(foo)
Error in rbindlist(foo) : 
  Item 2 has 12 columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 49183 columns
```

It seems to be a relatively easy thing to do, but I am not familiar with shapefiles. How can I approach this situation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To read your shapefile, i recommend you to use `rgdal` package and its `readOGR` function, or eventually use `readShapeLines` from `maptools` package. These packages rely on the `sp` package as concerning how the geospatial data is structured in R.

You can do easily this to convert your shapefile into `data.frame` (ie extract the attributes of the shapefile)

```
require(rgdal)
foo <- readOGR(dsn=".",layer="ne_10m_roads_north_america")
foo.df <- as(foo, "data.frame")
```

And that's it!

Note: If we compare `readOGR` and `readShapeLines` in term of performance, `readShapeLines` seems to give better results:

-with `readOGR`

```
user  system elapsed
114.48    7.34  123.83
```

-with `readShapeLines`

```
user  system elapsed 
76.28    0.43   78.05
```

Comment: Nice and easy. Or simply execute `foo.df <- foo@data`. Same result!

Comment: exactly! you can accessing the ``data`` slot in this way, or doing ``slot(foo, "data")``. ``as.data.frame`` is more a convenience method here useful for people who don't necessarily know about ``S4`` and ``slots``.

Comment: All roads lead to Rome ;-)

Comment: @flowla @eblondel I see. I use `readOGR` to read files from GADM. I should have thought about the package. If you want to read shapelines, `readShapeLines()` is the safest? `readOGR()` good for polygon? and lines?

Comment: interesting point... i've now compared performance of ``readOGR`` vs. ``readShapeLines``, and the latest gives faster results.

Comment: @eblondel Thank you for your support. I will play with `readShapeLines()` now.

Answer (score 2):

Please read the sp vignette on spatial classes and methods.

```
vignette(package="sp")[4]
  vignette("intro_sp")
```

Since there is a slot (@data) that holds a data.frame related to the sp object, no coercion is required.

```
class(foo@data)
str(foo@data)
( df <- foo@data )
```

However, it is good practice to operate directly on the @data slot rather than pulling it to a new object. Not only is it more efficient it also avoids breaking the relationship between the row order and the slots in the sp object it relates to.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. I will have a look of that. Cheers.

Comment: Note; I only use maptools shape read functions when I have broken topology. Otherwise, readOGR is a reliable generic method that can handle read/write of many vector formats all within the same function. It also retains projection information of the data. The same package, rgdal also handles raster formats.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Broom](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/broom.pdf) package.

Simply run:

```
my_df <- tidy(foo)
```